# Fetch records from specific month and year in php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have table where records are stored in 9/23/2014 this format of date.
I have searched a lot but all the result which i got there were in timestamp format(2013-12-27).

Can anybody help me, how retrieve data from specific month (say 'september' 2014)

Many thanks if help.

```
   Table: events

  id      course      description    date         start      end   
  1       john         test         9/23/2014     1:00pm    3:00pm
  2       brad         play         12/30/2014    5:00pm    8:00pm

 My Code:

        SELECT date FROM events WHERE MONTHNAME(date) = 'September' AND YEAR(date) = '2014'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use BETWEEN -

```
SELECT * 
FROM `events` 
WHERE `date` BETWEEN '2013-09-01' AND '2013-09-30';
```

Because your dates are stored as `varchar`'s (you really should fix that) you'll have to convert the string to a date format and then search. The performance will be awful though -

```
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(`date`, '%m/%/d/%Y %h:%i:%s %p') BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('2013-09-01', '%m/%/d/%Y') AND STR_TO_DATE('2013-09-30', '%m/%/d/%Y')
```

or

```
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(LEFT(`date`,LOCATE(' ',`date)),'%m/%d/%Y') BETWEEN '2013-09-01' AND '2013-09-30';
```

You can also use this method (although I prefer the first because of the control it offers) -

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE YEAR(`date_column`) = 2013 AND MONTH(`date_column`) = 9;
```

EDIT: Updated to reflect the OP's table schema. You should always check [reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) information before naming your columns.

Comment: It's worth noting that the first query can take advantage of an index on `date_column` while the second one can not

Comment: I have updated the question with mysql schema and my query.Please help me

Comment: What column type do you have on your date column? The format doesn't appear to be correct.

Comment: See basically i used jquery date picker and date column type is varchar thats why date is saved in 9/23/2014 format

Comment: Yes Jay Blanchard mysql return 0 results

Comment: Thanks @ Jay Blanchard sqlfiddle.com really worked for me. tons of thanks!!! you saved my time.

Answer (score 0):

Simple try this:

```
$query = mysqli_query($connect,'SELECT columns FROM tablename WHERE MONTHNAME(datecolumnn) = 'September' AND YEAR(datecolumn) = '2014');
```

;)

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE date_field BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT('%m/%d/%Y','2013-09-01') AND DATE_FORMAT('%m/%d/%Y','2013-09-30')
```

It should work.